# How do I build frameworks with Carthage targeting ARM and x86 targets?

Tags: ios, swift, carthage

I have a Swift based iOS framework and two specialised libraries I need to include in the framework. One is for ARM (device) and one for the simulator (x86).

How do I configure the framework project for use via Carthage to make use of these two libraries?

Comment: Sorry for answering my own question, but if anyone has any better ideas please send through anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is quite easy. It's necessary to `lipo` two architectures together.

Here, I'm taking a framework built for device (arm64) and simulator (x86_64) and making them into a fat framework called fat.

```
lipo -create -output "fat.framework/binary" "device.framework/binary" "simulator.framework/binary"
```

If making a release binary for Carthage, for saving in Github releases or similar, I've found `carthage archive` to be more reliable than archiving.